# Geoserver MVT - How to serve 'id' attribute per vector tile spec?

Tags: geoserver, vector-tiles, mapbox-gl-js

I am trying to work with MVT tiles served by a geoserver instance.

The [vector tile spec](https://github.com/mapbox/vector-tile-spec/tree/master/2.1) contains obligatory fields for `type` and `geometry`, and optional fields for `id` and `tags`.

The MVT tiles as served by the GeoServer instance leaves the `id` field as undefined, which isn't ideal when working with hover / selection workflows.

Is there a way to configure the GeoServer instance to automatically generate a unique id for populating the `id` field?

Example feature data as returned from mapbox `queryRenderedFeature`:

```
{
  type: "Feature",
  properties: {
    col_id: 'uniqueId',  <-- the table data contains a unique id
    col_1: 'some data',
    col_2: 'more data'
  },
  id: undefined,  <-- this "outer" MVT id is undefined
  geometry: ...
}
```

Comment: what sort of data source are you using? does it have a primary key?

Comment: yes, the data has a unique primary key, currently served inside the properties object.

Comment: could you add an example of the id - if it's the "wrong" format or too large it won't be added to the output. Other issue is what version of GeoServer are you using?

Comment: @ianTurton the primary id on the tables are strings, for example: "abcd1000001802738274". (That is the ids served inside the "properties" attribute alongside other column data for the source table.)

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by served inside the properties attribute - can you include an example feature in your question using the [edit] button

Comment: @ianTurton have added an example feature. The properties attribute being the table data returned by geo server.

Comment: @IanTurton It is running on Geoserver 2.15.2. The primary id is a `long` integer type.

Comment: can you go to the layer page in GeoServer and cut and paste the lines below Feature Type Details at the bottom of the page. This will give us some information to answer your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GeoServer MVT generates the id if your source data has:

- A Numeric primary key (or numeric identifier in whatever source is available)
- The value is a valid 32 bits integer.

Has been implemented in https://osgeo-org.atlassian.net/browse/GEOS-8875 so it should be part of 2.15.2, but does not hurt to try out a more recent version.

Comment: Adding this comment for others running into this issue and unable to resolve due to reasons outside their control: Mapbox v1.7.0 now supports a `promoteId` option for sources. This will automatically furnish an MVT `id` based on a selected attribute.